# detect user role and if this particular user role show unique content (Wordpress PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried everything and have been searching high and low; I am seeking to write a PHP solution that sniffs out what user role is logged; eg a custom user role named 'Site Manager' and if that user role is logged in.. show a unique hyper link.

Or even, all user types / roles EXCEPT 'Site Managers' hide link.

I have tried the below but it does not work.. Please note no special privileges has been defined for Site Managers and am seeking not to create filters or anything like that; I just want to use 'if user logged in as this role' then show.

```
<?php 
global $user_login, $current_user; 

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
    if (in_array('site managers', $user_info->roles)) { 
?>    
<li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wpcsv-export.csv">Download Inventory of Mobile Apps</a></li>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

I tried the above but it won't work!

Comment: Firstly, there is no default site managers role in wordpress; something somewhere must have added this. Next, when you use `add_role` the first argument is the machine readable name for this, which does not accept spaces, and will be the value held within the role, so in this case, it has to be something like `site_managers` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing explicitly wrong with the code you presented. Confirm that the name/slug for **Site Managers** is as you have in your code `site managers`. The name is most likely `site_managers`.